# Is there any advantage on using async method of httpclient

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on an MVC 4 application. I've a controller where I make calls to some REST service using the `HttpClient` class. The controller is a normal controller and the actions are not described with `async` keyword. Do I get any gain of using `PostAsync` method of `HttpClient` class in this case? It's not a fire and forget call and I need the result returned from the service. The ASP.NET thread is going to be blocked anyway till it get the result and so is there advantage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any advantage in that case. You have to be either all the way async or all the way synchronous.

The single exception I can think of is when you have a singe synchronous MVC action starting off dozens of async, concurrent requests. In that case you burn one thread to coordinate dozens of others. That would be acceptable.

Side note: Async doesn't apply to most server apps, but in your case it seems like you could benefit from an all-async style solution because you are making a potentially long-running HTTP request. So you might switch to all-async for this one particular MVC action.

Comment: Great answer. I would have given a +2 if possible.

Comment: Is surprising to see that HttpClient doesn't have synchronous methods

Comment: @Mark, I think it is made for WinRT scenarios. Use WebClient.